# I am trying to build an existing Java Web Dynamic Project, then I get this error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web-development-server

I am importing an existing project for Java Dynamic Web Project. When I run the project I get this error, I cannot understand the error even after an extensive google search. I am kinda newbei in the Dynamic Web Project. Is there any way to solve the problem. Could it be the JRE incompatible or apache incompatible?

**I changed the JRE Version and rebuild it and I get this another error**

```
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.96
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jul 24 2019 13:00:10 UTC
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.96.0
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Mac OS X
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.15.1
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86_64
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b15
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/lalthanpuiachhangte/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/lalthanpuiachhangte/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.96
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/lalthanpuiachhangte/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/lalthanpuiachhangte/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.96
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/Users/lalthanpuiachhangte/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/lalthanpuiachhangte/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.96/endorsed
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/lalthanpuiachhangte/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 473 ms
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.96
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:55 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/Users/lalthanpuiachhangte/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/citizen_2/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags/form is already defined
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/security/tags is already defined
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/lalthanpuiachhangte/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/citizen_2/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-0.9.29.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/lalthanpuiachhangte/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/citizen_2/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-jdk14-1.5.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /citizen/app.log (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:283)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1040)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:838)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:601)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:333)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:307)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5720)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/databaseContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/cctns_state_db] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5720)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/cctns_state_db] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:824)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:163)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 21 more

Nov 29, 2019 11:51:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: 
*****************************************************
* Owasp.CsrfGuard Properties
*
* Logger: org.owasp.csrfguard.log.ConsoleLogger
* NewTokenLandingPage: null
* PRNG: SHA1PRNG
* SessionKey: stov
* TokenLength: 32
* TokenName: stov
* Ajax: true
* Rotate: false
* TokenPerPage: false
* Action: org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Redirect
*   Parameter: Page = /citizen/invalidtoken.htm
* Action: org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Log
*   Parameter: Message = potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:%user%, ip:%remote_ip%, uri:%request_uri%, error:%exception_message%)
* Action: org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Rotate
*****************************************************

Nov 29, 2019 11:51:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/citizen] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:57 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:57 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 29, 2019 11:51:57 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2509 ms
```

Comment: Hi user7294900, I just changed the JRE version and another error pop up. Could it be JRE version in compatible